# Casting Object to BigNumber in Meteor DAPPs

Tags: dapps, meteor

`Web3` incorporates the `BigNumber` library in order to handle 256bit numbers.

I'm finding this problematic in Meteor as most of Meteor's reactive storage schemes such as `Session`, `ReactiveDict` and `collections` render `BigNumber` objects as simple JSON objects, thereby losing all the `BigNumber` functionality.  `ReactiveVar` has no such problem and preserves type.

Meteor can preserve object types as [`EJSON`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/ejson.html) but requires that the object have a custom `toEJSON()` function and a factory function added to the `EJSON` module for the custom type.

I haven't seen such coding for EJSON in the few DAPP examples around and am wondering how others are getting around such problems with BigNumber reactivity and storage?

For example, how does one display BigNumber from blockchain events which get stored in a Meteor collection as simple Objects?

```
amount: Object
c: Array[1]
e: 3
s: 1
```